# Variable and function are declared but not read when a const for nodemailer is declared

Tags: javascript, html, nodemailer

I am using a .js file and another .html file.
In the .js I declare a function that is called in the .html when a button is clicked.
The problem is that when I declare the constant to invoke the nodemailer, the function called in the .html is not read.

I already tried to declare the constant of require inside and outside the function where I use the module. Also, I've already searched for a response when a variable is declared but not used, but I still do not get response.

The line where the nodemailer is declared, is the one that causes the function not to be read:

```
function enviarCorreo(destinatario){
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
          pass: 'xxx'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
    from: 'lenguajesgerente@gmail.com',
    to: destinatario,
    subject: 'Información del Restaurante',
    text: informacionFinal(lstMeseros,lstCuentas),
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
    });
}
```

The next block of code is the function, which is declared in .js and read in .html, but when declaring "const nodemailer" it's not read:

```
function abrirOcerrar(){
    this.counter=counter+1;
    document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].innerText = this.counter;

}
```

I need the function to be read, as if the declaration of the constant nodemailer did not exist.

Comment: `nodemailer` is a [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/) package to send emails and it runs on the server, which is not available on the browser, that's why you're getting an error.

Comment: So could you recommend me something to send emails? @ZohirSalak

Comment: What do you mean by "*the function is not read.*"? Are you getting an error? Which one?

Comment: The error is shown in the code, the error appears: " 'abrirOcerrar' is declared but it's value is never read". @Bergi

Comment: @vinix i haven't done much work with emails, i don't think i can recommend anything that has to do with emails.

Comment: @vinix: You cannot send emails from the browser.  You need server-side code.